# Meaning of for (int x : temps) in C++

Tags: c++

here's some c++ code.

```
vector<double> temps;
for (double temp; cin>>temp;) 
temps.push_back(temp); 
double sum = 0;
for (int x : temps) sum += x; //what is this doing? 
cout << "Average temperature:
```

So the line:

```
 for (int x : temps) sum += x;
```

What is it doing? Where is sum's value coming from?

Comment: ill write this as a comment> check out ranged based loop http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html

Comment: Are you asking about the `for (int x : temps)` part, or the `sum += x` part?

Comment: I'm talking about (for int x:   temps) part mostly. I know that sum += x is just another way of typing sum = sum + x

Comment: the, I've removed whole bunch of unrelated text from your post (as noone cares about *your* smartness as long as post contains enough information). Please make sure remaining text clearly specify your problem.

Comment: I cared... I cared...

Comment: Okay, because you asked, "Where is sum's value coming from?" which suggested that you didn't understand what `sum += x;` means.

Comment: I don't understand anything, but that isn't your problem.

Comment: The previous dupe target was wrong. I've edited the list to point to the correct target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an enhanced for loop, it's pretty much a nicer way of writing regular for loops, and without the variable used to index arrays. It's the equivalent of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); i++)
    sum += temps.at(i);
```

Comment: You mean `temps.size()`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes I do :P thanks for pointing that out, haven't done c++ for a while

Comment: Wonderful! This answer is the shiznit! You sir, are probably wonderful with the ladies.

Answer (score 4):

`for(int x : temp) { sum += x; }` is defined as being equivalent to:

```
for ( auto it = begin(temp); it != end(temp); ++it ) 
{ 
    int x = *it;
    sum += x;
}
```

For a vector, `begin(temp)` resolves to `temp.begin()`, and `auto` resolves to `vector::iterator`.  The new syntax is easier to read and write, obviously.

Comment: Thus far this is the only decent answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a C++11 [range-based for loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for_loop) over the contents of the vector `temps`.

`x` takes each value in that vector, and the body of the loop (`sum += x`) increments `sum` by `x` for each value. The result is that `sum` is the sum over all values in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

`for (int x : temps)` means loop over `temps`, get every element in x, `sum += x;` means summarize `x` to `sum`. At last you'll get the summing value.

Reference for [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Answer (score 0):

`x` gets its value from the elements in the vector `temp`.

The loop:

```
for(int x : temp)
```

is a c++11 style loop that just runs over (iterates) each element in the vector and copies it into `x`. Then `x` can be using within the body of the loop.

Comment: So x is equal to the number of elements? Or the first element or what?

Comment: On the 1st iteration x is equal to temp[0], on the 2nd iteration x is equal to temp[1], etc....